# how to load external file through php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, curl

I am trying to load JS file through curl request and load it in my app.

I have something like

loadJS.php

```
 $c = curl_init('http://partnerSite.com/test.js');
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

       $jsFile = curl_exec($c);
        //I have tried this, give me error
        echo $jsFile;  

         //I have tried this and give me error too.
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($jsFile); 

        curl_close($c);
```

In my JS

```
  var url = '/loadoutSideJS'; redirect to loadJS.php
    $http({
            url:url,
            method:'GET',
         dataType:'json'
    }).success(function(data) {
        $.getScript(data);
   })
```

I am getting 414 request-url too large error in the console

For some reason, the response is treated as plain texts instead of js file. Is there anyway I can make the response treated as JS to load the external JS file? Thanks a lot!

**Updated**

loadJS.php

```
 $c = curl_init('http://partnerSite.com/test.js');
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

       $jsFile = curl_exec($c);       

         //I have tried this and give me error too.
        header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
        echo $jsFile; 

        curl_close($c);
```

In my JS

```
  var url = '/loadoutSideJS'; redirect to loadJS.php
    $http({
            url:url,
            method:'GET'            
    }).success(function(data) {
        $.getScript(data);
   })
```

Comment: why are you GETting the payload of the first request in the second? i also don't see why a url needs to be JSON encoded if it's the complete response body; that would make the url not a url, but something that started with `"` instead...

Comment: @dan: probably an attempt a proxying JS scripts via OP's server to bypass same-origin restrictions. but json_encoding the output is just redundant, since you could just sent it out as text/javascript in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB: but scripts need not follow the SOP, so that can't be it. the header after the echo, and the un-commented JS comment tells me that there's a lot of reasons this ain't working, so who knows...

Comment: please the updated answer, I hope i fixed the issues you guys mentioned. It is still not working for me though. (same error)

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo file_get_contents('http://partnerSite.com/test.js');
```